# Add new post to XML file

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<messages>
<post>
<id>1</id>
<userName>lala</userName>
<text>some nice text</text>
<timePosted>12456754</timePosted>
</post>
</messages>
```

I want to add a new post to messages, how do I do it? I tried adding it with addChild, didn't work.

Comment: Please show us your current code / attempt.  Also, what "didn't work" with `addChild`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Load the XML file
$xml = simplexml_load_file($filename);

// Create a new child node
$child = $xml->addChild('post');
$child->addChild('id', $id);
$child->addChild('userName', $username);
$child->addChild('text', $text);
$child->addChild('timePosted', $timeposted);

// Save the updated XML back to the file
$xml->asXML($filename);
```